# Reference C++ Dll in my project

Tags: c#

I have to reference a dll not created by me in C# project. When I tried to add reference I am getting the error that the dell could not be added. I tried to use TlbImp.exe like:

```
TlbImp.exe 'C:\\Desktop\PCMiler\pcmsrv64.dll'
```

I am getting the error that the dll is not a valid type library.

Then I tried

```
[DllImport("C:\\VSProjects\\PCMilerConnect\\pcmsrv64.dll")]
```

But it didn't work.
I also tried:

```
regsvr32 'C:\\Desktop\PCMiler\pcmsrv64.dll'
```

And I got the error that the dll was loaded but the entry-point was not found.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: TblImp and regsvr32 are for COM DLLs, which this isn't. Read [ask] and explain how your DllImport isn't working. For starters you really should use a relative path.

Comment: @Lio can you show the function declaration you are applying the `DllImport` to?

Comment: please post code and not screenshots!

Comment: Also, you _still_ haven't posted the error message that you get when you try to use `DllImport`. Also, why did you write `int` twice in the declaration?

Comment: I don't have access to the method signature. Just the documentation that I posted

Comment: @Lio do you really have no information on the types of parameters the function expects? That's very unusual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you tried it using

```
[DllImport("C:\\VSProjects\\PCMilerConnect\\pcmsrv64.dll")]
```

is correct, but as the error message states, you need to specify an *entry point*.
What that means is that you if the C++ function you want to call is named `DoFoo()` you need to import the Dll as follows using the function as entry point:

```
[DllImport("C:\\VSProjects\\PCMilerConnect\\pcmsrv64.dll", EntryPoint="DoFoo")]
```

An entry point is the [function name or ordinal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.entrypoint(v=vs.110).aspx).
See also [DllImport attribute documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

EDIT: Try if this works for you:

```
[DllImport("C:\\VSProjects\\PCMilerConnect\\pcmsrv64.dll", EntryPoint="PCMSLookup")]
public static extern int PCMSLookup(Trip tripId, string placeName, int easyMatch);
```

Provided that you also have defined a struct called `Trip` in C# which resembles the C++ side `Trip`.

EDIT 2:
You said you do not have access to the signature, so I believe instead of passing a `Trip` you are likely passing an `int`. Try this:

```
[DllImport("C:\\VSProjects\\PCMilerConnect\\pcmsrv64.dll", EntryPoint="PCMSLookup")]
public static extern int PCMSLookup(int tripId, string placeName, int easyMatch);
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? The question seems to indicate that the error message you are referring to was when the OP used regsvr32, not when using DllImport. When I have used DllImport I didn't need to use `EntryPoint`.

Comment: @Default thanks for clearing that up, yes, the error message about the entry point seemingly occurred only when using `regsvr32`, but as OP did not state *what* error he gets ("I tried it but it didn't work") when trying `DllImport` I thought maybe it could be that as well.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to use "PCMSLookup()"

Comment: @Lio alright, can you show me the definition of the function (e.g return type, parameters) so then I can try to set up a working solution for you